# Read logging.properties of JUL automatically

Tags: java.util.logging

Is it possible to make my webapp to recognize the logging.properties with no modifications in my side?

Comment: What servlet container? I assume you want the webapp to repspond to edits applied to the logging.properties while running?

Comment: say `tomcat` continer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Tomcat, you can setup a [WatchedResource](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) to point to your [logging.properties](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) and it will reload the web application if it is updated.  You'll have to do testing to make sure the reloads don't trigger any classloader memory leaks.

You can use [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LoggingMXBean.html) to modify logger levels while the application is running.  Or you have to resort to writing custom code using the [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to monitor the logging.properties file and call LogManager.readConfiguration.

Comment: So, there's no container-agnostic way?

Comment: No.  It is a limitation of the LogManager.